# Identity theorem of powerseries proof question

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, proof-explanation

I have proved that

> if the radius of convergence for $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ is positive and not all $a_n$ are Zero then there is a circle around $0$ which has at most finitely many zero points in $f$.

How can I derrive from that the identity Theorem of Powerseries which is:

The powerseries

$$f(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+...$$

$$g(z)=b_0+b_1z+b_2z^2+...$$

both have radius of convergence $\neq 0$.

If $(z_k)$ is a Zero convergent series with $z_k\neq 0$ and $(z_k) = g(z_k)$ for all $k$.

I don't understand what's written in parethesis and what follows now

(For example $f(z)=g(z)$ in a disk around $0$)

Then $a_n=b_n$ for all $n=1,2,...$

**I don't understand how I can derive from the previous result this result like I have already said, in the book there is also no further explaination. They have described the Identitys-theorem just as an application of the first Theorem I have stated.**

Please help me

Comment: The way you wrote the identity theorem is confusing. What book are you referring to?